# Gimp script and choosing an scheme interpretor?

Tags: debian, scripting, gimp

I came across this script https://twentymegahertz.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/gimp-script-for-image-sharpening-using-grain-extract/ which is basically a script to sharpen images.

Now I don't know `scheme` so I have absolutely no idea how to run it the script. Usually you save shell scripts as `shellscript.sh` but probably that is not the right way in this case. Also there are quite a few scheme binaries out there so which one is either most used or would be most right for gimp I have no idea. Can anybody help ?

```
 aptitude search scheme
p   chezscheme                                                                      - Reliable, high performance Scheme compiler                                                
p   chezscheme9.5                                                                   - Reliable, high performance Scheme compiler (version 9.5)                                  
p   chezscheme9.5-dbgsym                                                            - debug symbols for chezscheme9.5                                                           
p   chezscheme9.5-dev                                                               - Reliable, high performance Scheme compiler (C development files)                          
p   chezscheme9.5-doc                                                               - Reliable, high performance Scheme compiler (documentation)                                
p   cmuscheme48-el                                                                  - Emacs mode specialized for Scheme48                                                       
p   compass-color-schemer-plugin                                                    - create color schemes with ease                                                            
i A gedit-plugin-color-schemer                                                      - Color Schemer plugin for gedit                                                            
p   ifscheme                                                                        - scheme control for network interfaces                                                     
p   libcolor-scheme-perl                                                            - Perl module to generate pleasant color schemes                                            
p   libghc-recursion-schemes-dev                                                    - generalized bananas, lenses and barbed wire                                               
v   libghc-recursion-schemes-dev-5.0.2-b8128                                        -                                                                                           
p   libghc-recursion-schemes-doc                                                    - generalized bananas, lenses and barbed wire; documentation                                
p   libghc-recursion-schemes-prof                                                   - generalized bananas, lenses and barbed wire; profiling libraries                          
v   libghc-recursion-schemes-prof-5.0.2-b8128                                       -                                                                                           
p   mit-scheme                                                                      - MIT/GNU Scheme development environment                                                    
p   mit-scheme-dbg                                                                  - MIT/GNU Scheme debugging files                                                            
p   mit-scheme-dbgsym                                                               - debug symbols for mit-scheme                                                              
p   mit-scheme-doc                                                                  - MIT/GNU Scheme documentation                                                              
v   plt-scheme                                                                      -                                                                                           
v   plt-scheme-doc                                                                  -                                                                                           
v   scheme-r5rs                                                                     -                                                                                           
v   scheme-srfi-7                                                                   -                                                                                           
p   scheme2c                                                                        - Joel Bartlett's fabled Scheme->C system                                                   
p   scheme2c-doc                                                                    - Documentation for the Scheme->C system                                                    
p   scheme48                                                                        - simple, modular, and lightweight Scheme implementation                                    
p   scheme48-dbgsym                                                                 - Debug symbols for scheme48                                                                
p   scheme48-doc                                                                    - Documentation for the Scheme48 implementation of Scheme                                   
p   scheme9                                                                         - Scheme 9 from Empty Space R4RS Scheme interpreter                                         
p   scheme9-dbgsym                                                                  - debug symbols for scheme9                                                                 
p   sigscheme                                                                       - Scheme Interpreter to be embedded                                                         
p   sigscheme-dbgsym                                                                - debug symbols for sigscheme                                                               
p   sigscheme-runtime                                                               - Runtime for sigscheme Scheme interpreter                                                  
p   tinyscheme                                                                      - Very small scheme implementation                                                          
p   tinyscheme-dbgsym                                                               - Debug symbols for tinyscheme
```

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of placing the script in the appropriate gimp directory? See [Installing Script-Fus](https://docs.gimp.org/en/install-script-fu.html)

Comment: wish you had given it as an answer. Put it as an answer an I'll take it as an answer than create a follow-up question for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the script in the appropriate gimp directory.
See [Installing Script-Fus](https://docs.gimp.org/en/install-script-fu.html) for a specific answer, and more background info can be found at the [Gimp Scripting Table of Contents](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-scripting.html)